# ¿Cómo usar str_detect en un data.frame?

Tags: r, string, r-dplyr

Por ejemplo teniendo una columna con la siguiente información:

```
 columna <- data.frame( "columna" = c ("manolo sale entra pepe", 
                                       "rosa sale entra maria",
                                       "antonio sale entra jose"))
```

Como podría crear dos columnas nuevas "sale" y "entra" con los nombres de los que salen y entran.
Entiendo que seria usando mutate y str_detect, pero no se como seleccionar los nombres antes de la palabra "sale" y los de después de la palabra "entra"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el orden fuera siempre el mismo: sale -> entra, podrías usar directamente `separate()` y tomar `entra` como separador:

```
columna %>% 
  separate(columna, into=c("Col1", "Col2"), sep="entra ") %>% 
  mutate(Col2 = paste("entra", Col2)) # Como entra es separador, lo agregamos nuevamente
```

O bien, con expresiones regulares y `str_extract()`:

```
columna %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = str_extract(columna, ".*\\bsale\\b"),
         Col2 = str_extract(columna, "\\bentra\\b.*"))
```

El patrón `.*\\bsale\\b` significa 1) cualquier caracter, hasta 2) un separador de palabra seguido por 3) `sale` y 4) otro separador de palabra, algo similar se hace con `entra`

Comment: Como siempre muchísimas gracias Patricio